# No ports available

Tags: arduino-uno

Heyy everyone!!! I have just started working on arduino uno board and for the first week it was working fine but yesterday when I plugged in the usb cable the port option in IDE turned gray(showing no ports).
I tried to update drivers by following commands as given on  forum but arduino.inf file was not there under the drivers folder.
Also mega 16u2 ic on my board gets hot as soon as I connect it with usb . Tx and Rx LEDs are constantly glowing and 13 pin led  glows just for a short time then goes off.
It would be of great help if someone can solve my problem:)

Answer (score 3):

> Also mega 16u2 ic on my board gets hot as soon as I connect it with usb .

Your board is electrically damaged and must either be replaced or be repaired by someone able to change out one or more failed surface mount components.

The time of those able to do so is commercially priced above the value of this board, so generally it would only be repaired by someone able to do so themselves, where time spent on a hobby project doesn't necessarily have the same economic value as time spent on paying work.